# How to extend the List class Of any type

Tags: vb.net, extension-methods

I am trying to learn class extensions and am running into difficulty when defining the type of variables accepted in my new methods & functions. I have this simple method that I want to add to the List object that would be a short-hand for removing the final element off the list.

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Module ListExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Sub RemoveLast(FromList As List(Of ))
        FromList.RemoveAt(FromList.Count - 1)
    End Sub
End Module
```

I don't know what to write inside the brackets for `List(Of )`. For numeric operations, I have heard that I am supposed to create duplicate versions of the method with each accepted numeric type. But I want to accept lists of any type, and don't want to create a hundred of this method.

What do I write?

Comment: `What do I write?` - `T`?

Comment: @GSerg it says "BC30002: Type 'T' is not defined"

Comment: `Sub RemoveLast(Of T)(FromList As List(Of T))`?

Comment: @Gserg Thank you!

Comment: See [Generic Procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/generic-procedures) in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Promoting GSerg's comment to an answer...)

You can write generic methods as extension methods; in fact, Linq is all generic extension methods.  The result would be something like this:

```vb
<Extension>
Public Sub RemoveLast(Of T)(ByVal this As List(Of T))
    this.RemoveAt(this.Count - 1)
End Sub
```

The generic argument will be inferred in the call, you don't need to specify it, e.g. this will work:

```vb
Dim myList As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3, 4}
myList.RemoveLast()
```